# ObservableCollection CollectionChanged event seems not to be firing – why?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, observablecollection

What’s wrong with this code? Clicking button1 doesn’t cause the messageBox to appear.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> aCollection2 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    myClass mc = new myClass();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        aCollection2.Add("a");
        aCollection2.Add("b");
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mc.myCollection = aCollection2;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mc.myCollection.Clear();
    }
}
```

With myClass defined:

```
class myClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public myClass()
    {
        myCollection.CollectionChanged += Changed;
    }

    void Changed(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myCollection.Count.ToString());
    }
}
```

EDIT:
When I add a 3rd button with:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mc.myCollection.Add("a");
}
```

It does show the messageBox. And so does button2. But after clicking button1 – none will fire anymore. How come?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You added an event handler to the original `ObservableCollection` instance from your field initializer.
You never added an event handler to the new `ObservableCollection` instance from the form.
Since the original `ObservableCollection` never changes, your handler never runs.

This is one of the many reasons why [collection properties should be read only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx) (and [they should be properties, not fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182141.aspx))

Comment: @ispiro: Exactly.  It only fires when you modify the **original** `ObservableCollection`, not after you replace it.

Comment: Making the collection read-only revealed reassignments and saved me from lots of headaches.